# What is the nature of this C# string formatting?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

The following was taken from [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

```
_logger.LogInformation("Queued Background Task {Guid} is running. " +
                    "{DelayLoop}/3", guid, delayLoop);
```

What is this type of string formatting? In other words what is it called and where is it documented? Is it .NET or does it require a third party library?

Comment: It's called interpolation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: @Charleh: No it's not. Note the lack of a $ sign.

Comment: I assume the special format will be interpreted in the ```LogInformation``` method. That's not related to normal string formatting.

Comment: Its a custom implementation of the String.Format, but it works with the logger. String interpolation is used with the $ sign and converts a variable value to a string. Its from microsoft but with the logger

Comment: @imsmn: That is indeed the only possible explanation, but there seems to be a lack of connection between the {name} used and the values being passed. I guess we need to see the `LogInformation` method to rule out that some arbitrary magic values have been used, but they would be oddly specific arbitrary magic values.

Comment: @nalnpir: As has already been pointed out, the lack of a $ means that this is not string interpolation (at least not in the sense you're talking about)

Comment: The documentation might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lmt

Comment: Yep, you are right, it's not interpolation, so the question is what's the internal implementation using? I assume if the parameters supplied don't match the tokens in the string that it doesn't substitute

Comment: Its pure order of placeholders. Names are just a nice addition (or just misleading).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, have edited that term and link into my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's ASP.NET Core logging - or more generally, logging via `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`.

Although it *looks* a bit like C# interpolated string literals, the message is actually formatted by the logging infrastructure. The string is a [*message template*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-message-template). The names specified in the message template are entirely independent of the expressions provided later - but the *order* of the placeholders is expected to be the order of the values provided.

This allows logging provides to extract key/value pairs to perform structural logging... so for example you *could* end up with a log entry in JSON like this:

```json
{
  "message": "Queued Background Task 1234-5678[...] is running. 100/3",
  "properties": {
    "Guid": "1234-5678[...]",
    "DelayLoop": 100
  }
}
```

(It depends on the logging provider.)

Comment: I'll say that the parameters must be in the same order that they appear in the `{...}` templates, so `"Queued Background Task {Guid} is running. {DelayLoop}/3", delayLoop, guid` wouldn't work correctly

Comment: @xanatos: Good plan, will mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is built-in string formatting of this special library.
It's look like C# interpolated string but it's not C# interpolated. The library itself append the strings and parameters.