# proper way to use StreamWriter for a log file

Tags: c#, logging, streamwriter

FYI- the original poster cannot use open source or 3rd party libraries.

I am creating an application that will use a log file.
I want to know what is the "proper" way of creating a log file (in terms of System management, good practices, resources management etc.)

first method:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string path = "SomeFile.txt";
    StreamWriter writer;
    public Form1()
    {
        writer = new StreamWriter(path);
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void LogWriteLine(string print)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(print);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (writer != null) writer.Close();
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

second method:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string path = "SomeFile.txt";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void LogWriteLine(string print)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(print);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that in the second method I can view the log file online while in the first I can view the log file only after the application is closed, it's does not matter for my usage.

I would like to get a "general" answer if it is possible (for applications that will use the LogWriteLine a lot and for applications that rarely using it, if this is matters for this discussion).

Thank you.

Comment: The first method will be problematic if from that form you open another form and want to write in the same log file (as it should unless you want differentl logs for each class of your program) By the way,, do you know that there are many log libraries that will help you to not reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The problem you are mentioning is solvable, I am asking more as a general log management method, what is the "proper" way.
about the log libraries, no I did not know that, I will check it out, thank you.

Comment: @YakirShlezinger The "proper" way is that *at least* you have an external class that does the logging. The external class opens the file at start, and every write (or every x seconds) do a `Flush()`, to be sure the file is written. The file is opened with the options that other programs can open it for read. The `Write` method uses a `lock` to be sure there are not multiple writes at the same time, and so on and so on. There are even problems of switching log file and so on (you don't normally want to have a 1tb log file... every x time you switch).

Comment: (and in truth the "proper" way isn't even that... a good log is a hierarchical log, that is easily searchable, where text and values are keep separated... where every message has some attributes so that doing searches is possible. A text file is to a good log like a trashcan is to a library. For an example of what you an do with good logging, see an explanation of what ASP.NET Core logging can do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65090319/613130

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use outside code, I would suggest simple is good. There are multiple challenges with `StreamWriter`:

1] What if multiple threads want to log at the same time?
2] What about performance, shouldn't you keep a `StreamWriter` open all the time? (See #1).
3] What if you want to archive or delete logs?

Avoiding `StreamWriter` mostly solves these problems for you. Microsoft already provides a convenient append api.

```cs
public class Logger
{
    private readonly string file;

    public Logger(string file)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void Log(string text)
    {
        string line = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o") + " " + text + Environment.NewLine;

        // kick off log in background, don't slow main app down
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // try 10 times to log in the unlikely event two calls get at the file at the same time
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    // this avoids locking the log file in case it needs to be cleaned up, and adds a timestamp to each row.
                    await System.IO.File.AppendAllTextAsync(file, line);
                    break;
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    // wait a bit, unlikely to hit this but just in case...
                    await Task.Delay(20);
                }
            }
        }).GetAwaiter();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Logger logger = new Logger("c:/logs/log.txt"); // change to your path
logger.Log($"An event happend with data {data.Value}");
```

Comment: I can't use any framework that doesn't come from Microsoft, we are working in a stand alone high security network.

Comment: No worries. I updated with a simple logger class. You could expand it to make a new file name every day and rotate files, write as json, etc. if you want

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to performance and Optimization second way is proffered as #steve in the comments said

> The first method will be problematic if from that form you open
> another form and want to write in the same log file (as it should
> unless you want different logs for each class of your program)

However you should use the first way if you are willing to

1. Letting not the users to access logs while app is running
2. If the memory (RAM) is not a problem in your target device as this approach requires more memory

You should use second approach if you want to

1. Create general purpose logs for all modules in the app
2. Simplicity for logging
3. Put less burden on RAM
4. Let anyone access logs while the app is running

You should however use cloud logging in professional or release build for better performance and analysis such as Firebase or Custom Logging bridge